# Aligning the last line of text in a minipage environment with a line segment in a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I am trying to align the bottom of the last line of text in a minipage environment with line segment $\overline{AB}$ of $\triangle{ABC}$ in the accompanying tikzpicture diagram. I suspect that having minipage environment within a minipage environment is not proper formating - and unnecessary - but this should not be leading to the misalignment.

Also, what would my optional command be for the minipage environment if I wanted the vertices "$A$" and "$B$" to be aligned with the bottom of the last line of text? Would it be "current bounding box.south"?

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\usepackage{array, boldline, makecell}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[b]{4.5in}
\vskip0pt
\noindent \textbf{Theorem} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}{4.5in}
{\em An \textbf{isosceles triangle} is a triangle with two congruent sides; the congruent sides are called the \textbf{legs} of the isosceles triangle. If $\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ is an isosceles \\
triangle, and if $\overline{\mathit{AC}}$ and $\overline{\mathit{BC}}$ are its legs, $\angle\mathit{ABC}$ and $\angle\mathit{BAC}$
are the \textbf{base} \\
\textbf{angles} of the isosceles triangle, and they are congruent to each other.}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A)]

%An isosceles triangle is drawn. (The figure is magnified by 1/3.)
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at ({(1/3)*6},0);
\coordinate (C) at ({(1/3)*3},{(1/3)*9});

%The labels for the vertices are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};

%The triangle is drawn.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;


%Line segments AC and BC are marked with "|".
\draw ($($(A)!0.5!(C)$)!3pt!90:(C)$) -- ($($(A)!0.5!(C)$)!3pt!-90:(C)$);
\draw ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$)!3pt!90:(C)$) -- ($($(B)!0.5!(C)$)!3pt!-90:(C)$);


%A mark indicating the measure of $\angle{ABC}$ is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] let \n1={atan(3)} in ($(B) +({180-\n1}:0.4)$) arc ({180-\n1}:180:0.4);
\draw[blue] let \n1={atan(3)} in ($(B) +({180-0.5*\n1}:{0.4cm-3pt})$) -- ($(B) +({180-0.5*\n1}:{0.4cm+3pt})$);

%A mark indicating the measure of $\angle{BAC}$ is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] let \n1={atan(3)} in (0.4,0) arc (0:\n1:0.4);
\draw[blue] let \n1={atan(3)} in  ({0.5*\n1}:{0.4cm-3pt}) -- ({0.5*\n1}:{0.4cm+3pt});


\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a tikz node (if you give it a width) is a minipage, so it's probably more natural to do it all in tikz  rather than an explicit minipage outside the tikz picture.

Comment: there is no overline AB in the text -- what exactly is required-- the alignment of the minipage and triangle is shown in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the second minipage down by giving the `option [b]` in the following code

```
\noindent \begin{minipage}[b]{4.5in}
\vskip0pt
\noindent \textbf{Theorem} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}[b]{4.5in}%<----------------------------[b]
{\em An \textbf{isosceles triangle} is a triangle with two congruent sides; the congruent sides are called the \textbf{legs} of the isosceles triangle. If $\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ is an isosceles \\
triangle, and if $\overline{\mathit{AC}}$ and $\overline{\mathit{BC}}$ are its legs, $\angle\mathit{ABC}$ and $\angle\mathit{BAC}$
are the \textbf{base} \\
\textbf{angles} of the isosceles triangle, and they are congruent to each other.}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort to correcting my code. I decided to use David Carlisle's suggestion, though. I did not know that node command in TikZ is a minipage environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                calc,
                decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{4in}
\textbf{Theorem}\\

\hspace*{1em}
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr4in-2em\relax}\itshape
\textbf{Isosceles triangle} is a triangle with two congruent sides; the congruent sides are called the \textbf{legs} of the isosceles triangle. If $\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ is an isosceles triangle, and if $\overline{\mathit{AC}}$ and $\overline{\mathit{BC}}$ are its legs, $\angle\mathit{ABC}$ and $\angle\mathit{BAC}$ are the \textbf{base angles} of the isosceles triangle, and they are congruent to each other.
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2\baselineskip,
-|-/.style={decoration={markings,
  mark=at position 0.5 with {\draw (0,2pt) -- (0,-2pt);}},
  postaction={decorate}, line cap=round
            },
my angle/.style = {draw=blue, angle radius = 5mm},
                    ]
%An isosceles triangle is drawn. 
\coordinate[label=below:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:$B$] (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) at (1,3);

%The triangle with marks "|".
\draw[-|-] (A) -- (C);
\draw[-|-] (C) -- (B);
\draw   (B) -- (A);

%Draw angles.
\pic [my angle]     {angle = B--A--C};
\pic [my angle]     {angle = C--B--A};

% A mark indicating equal angles
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan(3)/2}
\draw[draw=blue] (A) ++ ( \ang: 4mm) -- ++ ( \ang: 2mm);
\draw[draw=blue] (B) ++ (-\ang:-4mm) -- ++ (-\ang:-2mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I try to make your image code simpler and shorter)

[image]